# Laravel AJAX GET and show new data

Tags: json, ajax, laravel, get

I've been working on a project and thus far I've been able to POST to the database using AJAX, so when the user submits data the page wont refresh but the data is still uploaded to the database.

Now what I want to do, is show those results to the user without needing to refresh the page. I've spent a lot of time trying to figure it out but right now I'm very stuck. Could anyone point me in the right direction? I've read the documentation on the website, watched hours worth of videos but still have no luck.

The code I have so far.

**Script**

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET', //THIS NEEDS TO BE GET
    url: '{{$video->id}}/shownew',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        $("#data").append(data);
    },
    error: function() { 
         console.log(data);
    }
});
```

**Controller**

```
public function shownew($video)
{
    $getstamps = DB::table('timestamps')
                    ->where('videoid', '=', $video)
                    ->orderByRaw('LENGTH(timestamp_time)', 'ASC')
                    ->orderBy('timestamp_time', 'asc')
                    ->get();

    return response()->json(array('success' => true, 'getstamps' => $getstamps));
}
```

**Console**

```
{success: true, getstamps: Array(3)}
getstamps: Array(3)
    0: {
        timestamp_id: 128,
        videoid: "5",
        timestamp_name: "Title",
        timestamp_time: 1,
        created_at: "2017-10-04 23:28:12",
        …
    }
    1: {
        timestamp_id: 129,
        videoid: "5",
        timestamp_name: "1",
        timestamp_time: 1,
        created_at: "2017-10-04 23:41:01",
        …
    }
    2: {
        timestamp_id: 130,
        videoid: "5",
        timestamp_name: "1",
        timestamp_time: 1,
        created_at: "2017-10-04 23:41:21",
        …
    }
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
success: true
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: How do  you want to want to apent the json data result to $("#data") ? here you need some logic in JS or you could use VUE.js

Comment: @Webdesigner I would like to use Javascript to append the data, but I also have a delete button which uses csrf_field() and the method delete. I'm unsure how I could implement it in such a way to keep the delete functionality. Also, the data isnt actually being appended. That part isnt working and the console shows no errors

Comment: What has the delete function to do with appending data to your page? If you get the right json data from your Laravel with your ajax reqest than this not a Laravel nor an Ajax question just JS and jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixed the issue.

```
        $.ajax({
        type: 'GET', //THIS NEEDS TO BE GET
        url: '{{$video->id}}/shownew',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            container.html('');
            $.each(data, function(index, item) {
            container.html(''); //clears container for new data
            $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                  container.append('<div class="row"><div class="ten columns"><div class="editbuttoncont"><button class="btntimestampnameedit" data-seek="' + item.timestamp_time + '">' +  new Date(item.timestamp_time * 1000).toUTCString().match(/(\d\d:\d\d:\d\d)/)[0] +' - '+ item.timestamp_name +'</button></div></div> <div class="one columns"><form action="'+ item.timestamp_id +'/deletetimestamp" method="POST">' + '{!! csrf_field() !!}' +'<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE"><button class="btntimestampdelete"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-trash buttonicon"></i></button></form></div></div>');
          });
                container.append('<br>');
            });
        },error:function(){ 
             console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

here is the solution for you problem

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET', //THIS NEEDS TO BE GET
    url: '{{$video->id}}/shownew',
    success: function (data) {
        var obj = JSON.parse(data);
        var your_html = "";
        $.each(obj['getstamps'], function (key, val) {
           your_html += "<p>My Value :" +  val + ") </p>"
        });
         $("#data").append(you_html); //// For Append
         $("#mydiv").html(your_html)   //// For replace with previous one
    },
    error: function() { 
         console.log(data);
    }
});
```